# particular solution guessing of a Riccati equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

> I can construct the general solution of a **Riccati equation** if a particular solution is known. Is there any guessing trick do exist for example:
>   $$\text{For }y'+y^2=\frac{2}{x^2} \text{ seek for a P.S. in the form }y=\frac{c}{x}$$
>   $$\text{For }x^3y'+x^2y-y^2=2x^4 \text{ seek for a P.S. in the form }y=cx^2$$
>   $\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\vdots$

Why seeking for a particular solution$(\text{P.S.})$ in that form$?$ And how the knew that will be work$?$ I really appreciated any kind of help.

Answer (score 4):

Most textbook and course exercises will resolve into a usefull form when substituting $y=\frac{u'}{au}$ where $a$ is the coefficient of $y^2$ in $y'+ay^2=...$. Note that in advanced exercises and more practical applications, this will give a general second order linear ODE without a "nice" solution. In some cases the original equation will have poles, while the solution for $u$ remains bounded, the poles of $u$ correspond to roots of $u$ which might be easier to handle numerically.

---

For example, your *first equation* then transforms using $y=\frac{u'}u$ to $$x^2u''-2u=0$$ which is a Cauchy-Euler equation with basis solutions $x^m$ where $0=m(m-1)-2=(m-2)(m+1)$, so that $u=Ax^2+Bx^{-1}$.

In the *second equation*, the recipe gives $y=-\frac{x^3u'}{u}$ so that
$$
2x^4=-x^3\frac{x^3u''+3x^2u'}{u}+\color{blue}{x^3\frac{x^3u'^2}{u^2}}-x^2\frac{x^3u'}u\color{blue}{-\frac{x^6u'^2}{u^2}}
\\
0=x^2u''+4xu'+2u
$$
which is again Euler-Cauchy with $0=m(m-1)+4m+2=(m+2)(m+1)$, thus $u=Ax^{-1}+Bx^{-2}$.

Answer (score 2):

$$y'+y^2=\frac{2}{x^2} $$
You can try a solution like $y=ax^m$ then:
$$amx^{m-1}+a^2x^{2m}=2x^{-2}$$
We need to have all the eponents be equals so
$$m-1=2m \implies m=-1$$
You have that:
$$-a+a^2=2 \implies a=-1,a=2$$
It's the same trick for the second equation try $ax^m$
These equations you are given are really particular ones. And they are hard to solve if you only change the exponent on the right side.

Comment: \begin{align}
x^3(ay^m)^2+x^2(ay^m)-(ay^m)&=2x^4\\
ax^3y^{m-1}+ax^2y^m-a^2y^{2m}&=2x^4
\end{align}
How to deduce now?@ Isham

Comment: it's $y=ax^m$ @NajmunNahar and then you find that $m=2$ then find the constant $a$ Najm

Comment: If an m like this exists then $ax^m$ is a solution of the equation $$\begin{align} amx^3x^{m-1}+ax^2x^m-a^2x^{2m}&=2x^4 \end{align}$$

Comment: got it with $m=2$

Comment: Yes @NajmunNahar then you find the constant.